# Python, beyond the basics

Tags: python

I've gotten to grips with the basics of Python and I've got a small holiday which I want to use some of to learn a little more Python. The problem is that I have no idea what to learn or where to start. I'm primarily web development but in this case I don't know how much difference it will make.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, there are great ressources for advanced Python programming :

- Dive Into Python ([read it for free](http://www.diveintopython.net/))
- Online python cookbooks (e.g. [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/) and [there](http://the.taoofmac.com/space/Python/Grimoire))
- O'Reilly's Python Cookbook (see amazon)
- A funny riddle game : [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/)

Here is a list of subjects you must master if you want to write "Python" on your resume :

- [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [iterators and generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/231855#231855)
- [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators/1594484#1594484)

They are what make Python such a cool language (with the standard library of course, that I keep discovering everyday).

Comment: What about iterators exactly?

Comment: Do you think you could add some hyperlinks to the Python resume items?  I'd be interested in digging in there.

Comment: Done. Mostly stackoverflow links :-)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on exactly what you mean by "gotten to grips with the basics", I'd suggest reading through [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and typing/executing all the chapter code, then get something like [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Collective-Intelligence-Building-Applications/dp/0596529325/) and working through it - you'll learn python quite well, not to mention some quite excellent algorithms that'll come in handy to a web developer.

Answer (score 3):

Something great to play around with, though not a project, is [The Python Challenge](http://pythonchallenge.com).  I've found it quite useful in improving my python skills, and it gives your brain a good workout at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly loved the book [Programming Python.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009259) It has a large assortment of small projects, most of which can be completed in an evening at a leisurely pace.  They get you acquainted with most of the standard library and will likely hold your interest.  Most importantly these small projects are actually useful in a "day to day" sense.  The book pretty much only assumes you know and understand the bare essentials of Python as a language, rather than knowledge of it's huge API library.

I think you'll find it'll be well worth working through.

Answer (score 2):

I'll plug [Building Skills in Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python.html).   Plus, if you want something more challenging, [Building Skills in OO Design](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/oodesign.html) is a rather large and complex series of exercises.

Answer (score 2):

*The Python Cookbook* is absolutely essential if you want to master idiomatic Python. Besides, that's the book that made me fall in love with the language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest writing a non-trivial webapp using either Django or Pylons, something that does some number crunching.
No better way to learn a new language than commiting yourself to a problem and learning as you go!

Answer (score 1):

Write a web app, likely in [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) - the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/) will teach you a lot of good Python style.

Use some of the popular libraries like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) or the [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/). Both of these make extremely useful functions, which are hard to get right, available in a well-documented API.

In general, I'd stay away from libs that aren't well documented -
you'll bang your head on the wall trying to reverse-engineer them -
and libraries that are wrappers around C libraries, if you don't have
any C experience. I worked on wxPython code when I was still learning
Python, which was my first language, and at the time it was little
more than a wrapper around wxWidgets. That code was easily the ugliest
I've ever written.

I didn't get that much out of Dive Into Python, except for the dynamic import chapter - that's not really well-documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

People tend to say something along the lines of "The best way to learn is by doing" but I've always found that unless you're specifically learning a language to contribute to some project it's difficult to actually find little problems to tackle to keep yourself going.

A good solution to this is [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), which has a list of various programming\mathematics challenges ranging from simple  to quite brain-taxing. As an example, the first challenge is:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

And by problem #50 it's already getting a little tougher

> Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes

There are 208 in total, but I think some new ones get added here and there.

While I already knew python fairly well before starting Project Euler, I found that I learned some cool tricks purely through using the language so much. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Search "Alex Martelli", "Alex Martelli patterns" and "Thomas Wouters" on Google video. There's plenty of interesting talks on advanced Python, design patterns in Python, and so on.