# What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

What functionality does the [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) keyword in Python provide?

For example, I'm trying to understand this code<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):
    if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        yield self._leftchild
    if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        yield self._rightchild
```

And this is the caller:

```
result, candidates = [], [self]
while candidates:
    node = candidates.pop()
    distance = node._get_dist(obj)
    if distance <= max_dist and distance >= min_dist:
        result.extend(node._values)
    candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))
return result
```

What happens when the method `_get_child_candidates` is called?
Is a list returned? A single element? Is it called again? When will subsequent calls stop?

---

<sub>1. This piece of code was written by Jochen Schulz (jrschulz), who made a great Python library for metric spaces. This is the link to the complete source: [Module mspace](https://well-adjusted.de/~jrspieker/mspace/).</sub>

Comment: [Here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) you can read a full explanation.

Answer (score 17987, accepted):

To understand what [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) does, you must understand what *[generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)* are. And before you can understand generators, you must understand *[iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)*.

### Iterables

When you create a list, you can read its items one by one. Reading its items one by one is called iteration:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
1
2
3
```

`mylist` is an *iterable*. When you use a list comprehension, you create a list, and so an iterable:

```
>>> mylist = [x*x for x in range(3)]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

Everything you can use "`for... in...`" on is an iterable; `lists`, `strings`, files...

These iterables are handy because you can read them as much as you wish, but you store all the values in memory and this is not always what you want when you have a lot of values.

### Generators

Generators are *[iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)*, a kind of iterable **you can only iterate over once**. Generators do not store all the values in memory, **they generate the values on the fly**:

```
>>> mygenerator = (x*x for x in range(3))
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

It is just the same except you used `()` instead of `[]`. BUT, you **cannot** perform `for i in mygenerator` a second time since generators can only be used once: they calculate 0, then forget about it and calculate 1, and end after calculating 4, one by one.

### Yield

`yield` is a keyword that is used like `return`, except the function will return a generator.

```
>>> def create_generator():
...    mylist = range(3)
...    for i in mylist:
...        yield i*i
...
>>> mygenerator = create_generator() # create a generator
>>> print(mygenerator) # mygenerator is an object!
<generator object create_generator at 0xb7555c34>
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...     print(i)
0
1
4
```

Here it's a useless example, but it's handy when you know your function will return a huge set of values that you will only need to read once.

To master `yield`, you must understand that **when you call the function, the code you have written in the function body does not run.** The function only returns the generator object, this is a bit tricky.

Then, your code will continue from where it left off each time `for` uses the generator.

Now the hard part:

The first time the `for` calls the generator object created from your function, it will run the code in your function from the beginning until it hits `yield`, then it'll return the first value of the loop. Then, each subsequent call will run another iteration of the loop you have written in the function and return the next value. This will continue until the generator is considered empty, which happens when the function runs without hitting `yield`. That can be because the loop has come to an end, or because you no longer satisfy an `"if/else"`.

---

### Your code explained

*Generator:*

```
# Here you create the method of the node object that will return the generator
def _get_child_candidates(self, distance, min_dist, max_dist):

    # Here is the code that will be called each time you use the generator object:

    # If there is still a child of the node object on its left
    # AND if the distance is ok, return the next child
    if self._leftchild and distance - max_dist < self._median:
        yield self._leftchild

    # If there is still a child of the node object on its right
    # AND if the distance is ok, return the next child
    if self._rightchild and distance + max_dist >= self._median:
        yield self._rightchild

    # If the function arrives here, the generator will be considered empty
    # There are no more than two values: the left and the right children
```

*Caller:*

```
# Create an empty list and a list with the current object reference
result, candidates = list(), [self]

# Loop on candidates (they contain only one element at the beginning)
while candidates:

    # Get the last candidate and remove it from the list
    node = candidates.pop()

    # Get the distance between obj and the candidate
    distance = node._get_dist(obj)

    # If the distance is ok, then you can fill in the result
    if distance <= max_dist and distance >= min_dist:
        result.extend(node._values)

    # Add the children of the candidate to the candidate's list
    # so the loop will keep running until it has looked
    # at all the children of the children of the children, etc. of the candidate
    candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))

return result
```

This code contains several smart parts:

- The loop iterates on a list, but the list expands while the loop is being iterated. It's a concise way to go through all these nested data even if it's a bit dangerous since you can end up with an infinite loop. In this case, `candidates.extend(node._get_child_candidates(distance, min_dist, max_dist))` exhausts all the values of the generator, but `while` keeps creating new generator objects which will produce different values from the previous ones since it's not applied on the same node.
- The `extend()` method is a list object method that expects an iterable and adds its values to the list.

Usually, we pass a list to it:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But in your code, it gets a generator, which is good because:

1. You don't need to read the values twice.
2. You may have a lot of children and you don't want them all stored in memory.

And it works because Python does not care if the argument of a method is a list or not. Python expects iterables so it will work with strings, lists, tuples, and generators! This is called duck typing and is one of the reasons why Python is so cool. But this is another story, for another question...

You can stop here, or read a little bit to see an advanced use of a generator:

### Controlling a generator exhaustion

```
>>> class Bank(): # Let's create a bank, building ATMs
...    crisis = False
...    def create_atm(self):
...        while not self.crisis:
...            yield "$100"
>>> hsbc = Bank() # When everything's ok the ATM gives you as much as you want
>>> corner_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm()
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())
$100
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())
$100
>>> print([corner_street_atm.next() for cash in range(5)])
['$100', '$100', '$100', '$100', '$100']
>>> hsbc.crisis = True # Crisis is coming, no more money!
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>
>>> wall_street_atm = hsbc.create_atm() # It's even true for new ATMs
>>> print(wall_street_atm.next())
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>
>>> hsbc.crisis = False # The trouble is, even post-crisis the ATM remains empty
>>> print(corner_street_atm.next())
<type 'exceptions.StopIteration'>
>>> brand_new_atm = hsbc.create_atm() # Build a new one to get back in business
>>> for cash in brand_new_atm:
...    print cash
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
$100
...
```

**Note:** For Python 3, use`print(corner_street_atm.__next__())` or `print(next(corner_street_atm))`

It can be useful for various things like controlling access to a resource.

### Itertools, your best friend

The `itertools` module contains special functions to manipulate iterables. Ever wish to duplicate a generator?
Chain two generators? Group values in a nested list with a one-liner? `Map / Zip` without creating another list?

Then just `import itertools`.

An example? Let's see the possible orders of arrival for a four-horse race:

```
>>> horses = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> races = itertools.permutations(horses)
>>> print(races)
<itertools.permutations object at 0xb754f1dc>
>>> print(list(itertools.permutations(horses)))
[(1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 4, 3),
 (1, 3, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4, 2),
 (1, 4, 2, 3),
 (1, 4, 3, 2),
 (2, 1, 3, 4),
 (2, 1, 4, 3),
 (2, 3, 1, 4),
 (2, 3, 4, 1),
 (2, 4, 1, 3),
 (2, 4, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2, 4),
 (3, 1, 4, 2),
 (3, 2, 1, 4),
 (3, 2, 4, 1),
 (3, 4, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 2, 1),
 (4, 1, 2, 3),
 (4, 1, 3, 2),
 (4, 2, 1, 3),
 (4, 2, 3, 1),
 (4, 3, 1, 2),
 (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

### Understanding the inner mechanisms of iteration

Iteration is a process implying iterables (implementing the `__iter__()` method) and iterators (implementing the `__next__()` method).
Iterables are any objects you can get an iterator from. Iterators are objects that let you iterate on iterables.

There is more about it in this article about [how `for` loops work](https://web.archive.org/web/20201109034340/http://effbot.org/zone/python-for-statement.htm).

Comment: `yield` is not as magical this answer suggests. When you call a function that contains a `yield` statement anywhere, you get a generator object, but no code runs. Then each time you extract an object from the generator, Python executes code in the function until it comes to a `yield` statement, then pauses and delivers the object. When you extract another object, Python resumes just after the `yield` and continues until it reaches another `yield` (often the same one, but one iteration later). This continues until the function runs off the end, at which point the generator is deemed exhausted.

Comment: "These iterables are handy... but you store all the values in memory and this is not always what you want", is either wrong or confusing. An iterable returns an iterator upon calling the iter() on the iterable, and an iterator doesn't always have to store its values in memory, depending on the implementation of the __iter__ method, it can also generate values in the sequence on demand.

Comment: It would be nice to add to this **great** answer why *It is just the same except you used `()` instead of `[]`*, specifically what `()` is (there may be confusion with a tuple).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp "This continues until the function runs off the end" -- or it encounters a `return` statement. (`return` is permitted in a function containing `yield`, provided that it does not specify a return value.)

Comment: The yield statement suspends function’s execution and sends a value back to the caller, but retains enough state to enable function to resume where it is left off. When resumed, the function continues execution immediately after the last yield run. This allows its code to produce a series of values over time, rather than computing them at once and sending them back like a list.

Comment: So yield anywhere in a function makes the function a generator, which is basically an iterable of yields from a function?

Comment: @Zaffer Basically. Each call to the function creates a new `generator` object based on the generator function which can be iterated over independently. I sometimes wish there was a separate keyword like `codef` to define such functions, so that `yield` in a `def` would be a syntax error. (It *used* to be a syntax error to use both `return` and `yield` in the same function, but then `return` was allowed as a shortcut for raising `StopIteration`.)

Comment: Where `yield` is defined:

`>>> def create_generator():
...    mylist = range(3)`
should be:

`>>> def create_generator():
...    mylist = (x*x for x in range(3))` instead.

Comment: Interestingly, at least two different people used the `Bank` example from this answer... to ask duplicate questions about the meaning/necessity of `self`.

Answer (score 2544):

### Shortcut to understanding `yield`

When you see a function with `yield` statements, apply this easy trick to understand what will happen:

1. Insert a line `result = []` at the start of the function.
2. Replace each `yield expr` with `result.append(expr)`.
3. Insert a line `return result` at the bottom of the function.
4. Yay - no more `yield` statements! Read and figure out the code.
5. Compare the function to the original definition.

This trick may give you an idea of the logic behind the function, but what actually happens with `yield` is significantly different than what happens in the list-based approach. In many cases, the yield approach will be a lot more memory efficient and faster too. In other cases, this trick will get you stuck in an infinite loop, even though the original function works just fine. Read on to learn more...

### Don't confuse your iterables, iterators, and generators

First, the **iterator protocol** - when you write

```
for x in mylist:
    ...loop body...
```

Python performs the following two steps:

1. Gets an iterator for `mylist`:

   Call `iter(mylist)` -> this returns an object with a `next()` method (or `__next__()` in Python 3).

   [This is the step most people forget to tell you about]
2. Uses the iterator to loop over items:

   Keep calling the `next()` method on the iterator returned from step 1. The return value from `next()` is assigned to `x` and the loop body is executed. If an exception `StopIteration` is raised from within `next()`, it means there are no more values in the iterator and the loop is exited.

The truth is Python performs the above two steps anytime it wants to *loop over* the contents of an object - so it could be a for loop, but it could also be code like `otherlist.extend(mylist)` (where `otherlist` is a Python list).

Here `mylist` is an *iterable* because it implements the iterator protocol. In a user-defined class, you can implement the `__iter__()` method to make instances of your class iterable. This method should return an *iterator*. An iterator is an object with a `next()` method. It is possible to implement both `__iter__()` and `next()` on the same class, and have `__iter__()` return `self`. This will work for simple cases, but not when you want two iterators looping over the same object at the same time.

So that's the iterator protocol, many objects implement this protocol:

1. Built-in lists, dictionaries, tuples, sets, and files.
2. User-defined classes that implement `__iter__()`.
3. Generators.

Note that a `for` loop doesn't know what kind of object it's dealing with - it just follows the iterator protocol, and is happy to get item after item as it calls `next()`. Built-in lists return their items one by one, dictionaries return the *keys* one by one, files return the *lines* one by one, etc. And generators return... well that's where `yield` comes in:

```
def f123():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

for item in f123():
    print item
```

Instead of `yield` statements, if you had three `return` statements in `f123()` only the first would get executed, and the function would exit. But `f123()` is no ordinary function. When `f123()` is called, it *does not* return any of the values in the yield statements! It returns a generator object. Also, the function does not really exit - it goes into a suspended state. When the `for` loop tries to loop over the generator object, the function resumes from its suspended state at the very next line after the `yield` it previously returned from, executes the next line of code, in this case, a `yield` statement, and returns that as the next item. This happens until the function exits, at which point the generator raises `StopIteration`, and the loop exits.

So the generator object is sort of like an adapter - at one end it exhibits the iterator protocol, by exposing `__iter__()` and `next()` methods to keep the `for` loop happy. At the other end, however, it runs the function just enough to get the next value out of it and puts it back in suspended mode.

### Why use generators?

Usually, you can write code that doesn't use generators but implements the same logic. One option is to use the temporary list 'trick' I mentioned before. That will not work in all cases, for e.g. if you have infinite loops, or it may make inefficient use of memory when you have a really long list. The other approach is to implement a new iterable class `SomethingIter` that keeps the state in instance members and performs the next logical step in its `next()` (or `__next__()` in Python 3) method. Depending on the logic, the code inside the `next()` method may end up looking very complex and prone to bugs. Here generators provide a clean and easy solution.

Comment: *"When you see a function with yield statements, apply this easy trick to understand what will happen"* Doesn't this completely ignore the fact that you can `send` into a generator, which is a huge part of the point of generators?

Comment: "it could be a for loop, but it could also be code like `otherlist.extend(mylist)`" -> This is incorrect. `extend()` modifies the list in-place and does not return an iterable. Trying to loop over `otherlist.extend(mylist)` will fail with a `TypeError` because `extend()` implicitly returns `None`, and you can't loop over `None`.

Comment: @pedro You have misunderstood that sentence. It means that python performs the two mentioned steps on `mylist` (not on `otherlist`) when executing `otherlist.extend(mylist)`.

Answer (score 772):

Think of it this way:

An iterator is just a fancy sounding term for an object that has a `next()` method.  So a yield-ed function ends up being something like this:

Original version:

```
def some_function():
    for i in xrange(4):
        yield i

for i in some_function():
    print i
```

This is basically what the Python interpreter does with the above code:

```
class it:
    def __init__(self):
        # Start at -1 so that we get 0 when we add 1 below.
        self.count = -1

    # The __iter__ method will be called once by the 'for' loop.
    # The rest of the magic happens on the object returned by this method.
    # In this case it is the object itself.
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    # The next method will be called repeatedly by the 'for' loop
    # until it raises StopIteration.
    def next(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count < 4:
            return self.count
        else:
            # A StopIteration exception is raised
            # to signal that the iterator is done.
            # This is caught implicitly by the 'for' loop.
            raise StopIteration

def some_func():
    return it()

for i in some_func():
    print i
```

For more insight as to what's happening behind the scenes, the `for` loop can be rewritten to this:

```
iterator = some_func()
try:
    while 1:
        print iterator.next()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Does that make more sense or just confuse you more?  :)

I should note that this *is* an oversimplification for illustrative purposes. :)

Comment: `__getitem__` could be defined instead of `__iter__`. For example: `class it: pass; it.__getitem__ = lambda self, i: i*10 if i < 10 else [][0]; for i in it(): print(i)`, It will print: 0, 10, 20, ..., 90

Comment: I tried this example in Python 3.6 and if I create `iterator = some_function()`, the variable `iterator` does not have a function called `next()` anymore, but only a `__next__()` function. Thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Where does the `for` loop implementation you wrote call the `__iter__` method of `iterator`, the instantiated instance  of `it`?

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not true at all. This is not what python interpreter does with generators. It is not creating a class starting from the generator function and implement `__iter__` and `__next__`. What it is acutally doing under the hood is explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723893/how-does-a-generator-function-work-internally#comment78413677_45727729. To cite @Raymond Hettinger  *"generators are not implemented internally as shown in your pure python class. Instead, they share most of the same logic as regular functions"*

Answer (score 663):

The `yield` keyword is reduced to two simple facts:

1. If the compiler detects the `yield` keyword *anywhere* inside a function, that function no longer returns via the `return` statement. ***Instead***, it **immediately** returns a **lazy "pending list" object** called a generator
2. A generator is iterable. What is an *iterable*? It's anything like a `list`, `set`, `range`, dictionary view, or any other object with a *built-in protocol for visiting each element in a certain order*.

In a nutshell: Most commonly, **a generator is a lazy, incrementally-pending list**, and **`yield` statements allow you to use function notation to program the list values** the generator should incrementally spit out. **Furthermore, advanced usage lets you use generators as coroutines (see below).**

```py
generator = myYieldingFunction(...)  # basically a list (but lazy)
x = list(generator)  # evaluate every element into a list

   generator
       v
[x[0], ..., ???]

         generator
             v
[x[0], x[1], ..., ???]

               generator
                   v
[x[0], x[1], x[2], ..., ???]

                       StopIteration exception
[x[0], x[1], x[2]]     done
```

Basically, whenever the `yield` statement is encountered, the function pauses and saves its state, then emits "the next return value in the 'list'" according to the python iterator protocol (to some syntactic construct like a for-loop that repeatedly calls `next()` and catches a `StopIteration` exception, etc.). You might have encountered generators with [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/); generator functions are more powerful because you can pass arguments back into the paused generator function, using them to implement coroutines. More on that later.

---

### Basic Example ('list')

Let's define a function `makeRange` that's just like Python's `range`. Calling `makeRange(n)` RETURNS A GENERATOR:

```py
def makeRange(n):
    # return 0,1,2,...,n-1
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

>>> makeRange(5)
<generator object makeRange at 0x19e4aa0>
```

To force the generator to immediately return its pending values, you can pass it into `list()` (just like you could any iterable):

```py
>>> list(makeRange(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

### Comparing the example to "just returning a list"

The above example can be thought of as merely creating a list that you append to and return:

```py
# return a list                  #  # return a generator
def makeRange(n):                #  def makeRange(n):
    """return [0,1,2,...,n-1]""" #      """return 0,1,2,...,n-1"""
    TO_RETURN = []               # 
    i = 0                        #      i = 0
    while i < n:                 #      while i < n:
        TO_RETURN += [i]         #          yield i
        i += 1                   #          i += 1
    return TO_RETURN             # 

>>> makeRange(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

There is one major difference, though; see the last section.

---

### How you might use generators

An iterable is the last part of a list comprehension, and all generators are iterable, so they're often used like so:

```py
#                  < ITERABLE >
>>> [x+10 for x in makeRange(5)]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

To get a better feel for generators, you can play around with the `itertools` module (be sure to use `chain.from_iterable` rather than `chain` when warranted). For example, you might even use generators to implement infinitely-long lazy lists like `itertools.count()`. You could implement your own `def enumerate(iterable): zip(count(), iterable)`, or alternatively do so with the `yield` keyword in a while-loop.

Please note: generators can actually be used for many more things, such as [implementing coroutines](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html), non-deterministic programming, and other elegant things. However, the "lazy lists" viewpoint I present here is the most common use you will find.

---

### Behind the scenes

This is how the "Python iteration protocol" works. That is, what is going on when you do `list(makeRange(5))`. This is what I describe earlier as a "lazy, incremental list".

```py
>>> x=iter(range(5))
>>> next(x)  # calls x.__next__(); x.next() is deprecated
0
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> next(x)
3
>>> next(x)
4
>>> next(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

The built-in function `next()` just calls the objects `.__next__()` function, which is a part of the "iteration protocol" and is found on all iterators. You can manually use the `next()` function (and other parts of the iteration protocol) to implement fancy things, usually at the expense of readability, so try to avoid doing that...

---

### Coroutines

[Coroutine](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) example:

```py
def interactiveProcedure():
    userResponse = yield makeQuestionWebpage()
    print('user response:', userResponse)
    yield 'success'

coroutine = interactiveProcedure()
webFormData = next(coroutine)  # same as .send(None)
userResponse = serveWebForm(webFormData)

# ...at some point later on web form submit...

successStatus = coroutine.send(userResponse)
```

A coroutine (generators that generally accept input via the `yield` keyword e.g. `nextInput = yield nextOutput`, as a form of two-way communication) is basically a computation that is allowed to pause itself and request input (e.g. to what it should do next). When the coroutine pauses itself (when the running coroutine eventually hits a `yield` keyword), the computation is paused and control is inverted (yielded) back to the 'calling' function (the frame which requested the `next` value of the computation). The paused generator/coroutine remains paused until another invoking function (possibly a different function/context) requests the next value to unpause it (usually passing input data to direct the paused logic interior to the coroutine's code).

**You can think of Python coroutines as lazy incrementally-pending lists, where the next element doesn't just depend on the previous computation but also on input that you may opt to inject during the generation process.**

---

### Minutiae

Normally, most people would not care about the following distinctions and probably want to stop reading here.

In Python-speak, an *iterable* is any object which "understands the concept of a for-loop" like a list `[1,2,3]`, and an *iterator* is a specific instance of the requested for-loop like `[1,2,3].__iter__()`. A *generator* is exactly the same as any iterator, except for the way it was written (with function syntax).

When you request an iterator from a list, it creates a new iterator. However, when you request an iterator from an iterator (which you would rarely do), it just gives you a copy of itself.

Thus, in the unlikely event that you are failing to do something like this...

```py
> x = myRange(5)
> list(x)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> list(x)
[]
```

... then remember that a generator is an *iterator*; that is, it is one-time-use. If you want to reuse it, you should call `myRange(...)` again. If you need to use the result twice, convert the result to a list and store it in a variable `x = list(myRange(5))`. Those who absolutely need to clone a generator (for example, who are doing terrifyingly hackish metaprogramming) can use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) ([still works in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee)) if absolutely necessary, since the [copyable iterator Python PEP standards proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0323/) has been deferred.

Answer (score 572):

> **What does the `yield` keyword do in Python?**

## Answer Outline/Summary

- A function with [**`yield`**](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr), when called, **returns a [Generator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators).**
- Generators are iterators because they implement the [**iterator protocol**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), so you can iterate over them.
- A generator can also be **sent information**, making it conceptually a **coroutine**.
- In Python 3, you can **delegate** from one generator to another in both directions with **`yield from`**.
- (Appendix critiques a couple of answers, including the top one, and discusses the use of `return` in a generator.)

## Generators:

**`yield`** is only legal inside of a function definition, and **the inclusion of `yield` in a function definition makes it return a generator.**

The idea for generators comes from other languages (see footnote 1) with varying implementations. In Python's Generators, the execution of the code is [frozen](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator) at the point of the yield. When the generator is called (methods are discussed below) execution resumes and then freezes at the next yield.

`yield` provides an
easy way of [implementing the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types), defined by the following two methods:
`__iter__` and `__next__`.  Both of those methods
make an object an iterator that you could type-check with the `Iterator` Abstract Base
Class from the `collections` module.

```
def func():
    yield 'I am'
    yield 'a generator!'
```

Let's do some introspection:

```
>>> type(func)                 # A function with yield is still a function
<type 'function'>
>>> gen = func()
>>> type(gen)                  # but it returns a generator
<type 'generator'>
>>> hasattr(gen, '__iter__')   # that's an iterable
True
>>> hasattr(gen, '__next__')   # and with .__next__
True                           # implements the iterator protocol.
```

The generator type is a sub-type of iterator:

```
from types import GeneratorType
from collections.abc import Iterator

>>> issubclass(GeneratorType, Iterator)
True
```

And if necessary, we can type-check like this:

```
>>> isinstance(gen, GeneratorType)
True
>>> isinstance(gen, Iterator)
True
```

A feature of an `Iterator` [is that once exhausted](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), you can't reuse or reset it:

```
>>> list(gen)
['I am', 'a generator!']
>>> list(gen)
[]
```

You'll have to make another if you want to use its functionality again (see footnote 2):

```
>>> list(func())
['I am', 'a generator!']
```

One can yield data programmatically, for example:

```
def func(an_iterable):
    for item in an_iterable:
        yield item
```

The above simple generator is also equivalent to the below - as of Python 3.3 you can use [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/):

```
def func(an_iterable):
    yield from an_iterable
```

However, `yield from` also allows for delegation to subgenerators,
which will be explained in the following section on cooperative delegation with sub-coroutines.

## Coroutines:

`yield` forms an expression that allows data to be sent into the generator (see footnote 3)

Here is an example, take note of the `received` variable, which will point to the data that is sent to the generator:

```
def bank_account(deposited, interest_rate):
    while True:
        calculated_interest = interest_rate * deposited 
        received = yield calculated_interest
        if received:
            deposited += received


>>> my_account = bank_account(1000, .05)
```

First, we must queue up the generator with the built-in function, [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next). It will
call the appropriate `next` or `__next__` method, depending on the version of
Python you are using:

```
>>> first_year_interest = next(my_account)
>>> first_year_interest
50.0
```

And now we can send data into the generator. ([Sending `None` is
the same as calling `next`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#specification-sending-values-into-generators).) :

```
>>> next_year_interest = my_account.send(first_year_interest + 1000)
>>> next_year_interest
102.5
```

### Cooperative Delegation to Sub-Coroutine with `yield from`

Now, recall that `yield from` is available in Python 3. This allows us to delegate coroutines to a subcoroutine:

```py
def money_manager(expected_rate):
    # must receive deposited value from .send():
    under_management = yield                   # yield None to start.
    while True:
        try:
            additional_investment = yield expected_rate * under_management 
            if additional_investment:
                under_management += additional_investment
        except GeneratorExit:
            '''TODO: write function to send unclaimed funds to state'''
            raise
        finally:
            '''TODO: write function to mail tax info to client'''
        

def investment_account(deposited, manager):
    '''very simple model of an investment account that delegates to a manager'''
    # must queue up manager:
    next(manager)      # <- same as manager.send(None)
    # This is where we send the initial deposit to the manager:
    manager.send(deposited)
    try:
        yield from manager
    except GeneratorExit:
        return manager.close()  # delegate?
```

And now we can delegate functionality to a sub-generator and it can be used
by a generator just as above:

```py
my_manager = money_manager(.06)
my_account = investment_account(1000, my_manager)
first_year_return = next(my_account) # -> 60.0
```

Now simulate adding another 1,000 to the account plus the return on the account (60.0):

```py
next_year_return = my_account.send(first_year_return + 1000)
next_year_return # 123.6
```

You can read more about the precise semantics of `yield from` in [PEP 380.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics)

### Other Methods: close and throw

The `close` method raises `GeneratorExit` at the point the function
execution was frozen. This will also be called by `__del__` so you
can put any cleanup code where you handle the `GeneratorExit`:

```py
my_account.close()
```

You can also throw an exception which can be handled in the generator
or propagated back to the user:

```py
import sys
try:
    raise ValueError
except:
    my_manager.throw(*sys.exc_info())
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in money_manager
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError
```

## Conclusion

I believe I have covered all aspects of the following question:

> **What does the `yield` keyword do in Python?**

It turns out that `yield` does a lot. I'm sure I could add even more
thorough examples to this. If you want more or have some constructive criticism, let me know by commenting
below.

---

## Appendix:

### Critique of the Top/Accepted Answer**

- It is confused about what makes an **iterable**, just using a list as an example. See my references above, but in summary: an **iterable** has an `__iter__` method returning an **iterator**. An **iterator** additionally provides a `.__next__` method, which is implicitly called by `for` loops until it raises `StopIteration`, and once it does raise `StopIteration`, it will continue to do so.
- It then uses a generator expression to describe what a generator is. Since a generator expression is simply a convenient way to create an **iterator**, it only confuses the matter, and we still have not yet gotten to the `yield` part.
- In **Controlling a generator exhaustion** he calls the `.next` method (which only works in Python 2), when instead he should use the built-in function, `next`. Calling `next(obj)` would be an appropriate layer of indirection, because his code does not work in Python 3.
- Itertools? This was not relevant to what `yield` does at all.
- No discussion of the methods that `yield` provides along with the new functionality `yield from` in Python 3.

**The top/accepted answer is a very incomplete answer.**

### Critique of answer suggesting `yield` in a generator expression or comprehension.

The grammar currently allows any expression in a list comprehension.

```
expr_stmt: testlist_star_expr (annassign | augassign (yield_expr|testlist) |
                     ('=' (yield_expr|testlist_star_expr))*)
...
yield_expr: 'yield' [yield_arg]
yield_arg: 'from' test | testlist
```

Since yield is an expression, it has been touted by some as interesting to use it in comprehensions or generator expression - in spite of citing no particularly good use-case.

The CPython core developers are [discussing deprecating its allowance](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-January/147301.html).
Here's a relevant post from the mailing list:

> On 30 January 2017 at 19:05, Brett Cannon  wrote:
>
> > On Sun, 29 Jan 2017 at 16:39 Craig Rodrigues  wrote:
> >
> > > I'm OK with either approach.  Leaving things the way they are in Python 3
> > > is no good, IMHO.
> >
> > My vote is it be a SyntaxError since you're not getting what you expect from
> > the syntax.
>
> I'd agree that's a sensible place for us to end up, as any code
> relying on the current behaviour is really too clever to be
> maintainable.
>
> In terms of getting there, we'll likely want:
>
> - SyntaxWarning or DeprecationWarning in 3.7
> - Py3k warning in 2.7.x
> - SyntaxError in 3.8
>
> Cheers, Nick.
>
> --  Nick Coghlan   |   ncoghlan at gmail.com   |   Brisbane, Australia

Further, there is an [outstanding issue (10544)](http://bugs.python.org/issue10544) which seems to be pointing in the direction of this *never* being a good idea (PyPy, a Python implementation written in Python, is already raising syntax warnings.)

Bottom line, until the developers of CPython tell us otherwise: **Don't put `yield` in a generator expression or comprehension.**

### The `return` statement in a generator

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):

> In a generator function, the `return` statement indicates that the generator is done and will cause `StopIteration` to be raised. The returned value (if any) is used as an argument to construct `StopIteration` and becomes the `StopIteration.value` attribute.

<sub>Historical note, in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement):
"In a generator function, the `return` statement is not allowed to include an `expression_list`. In that context, a bare `return` indicates that the generator is done and will cause `StopIteration` to be raised."
An `expression_list` is basically any number of expressions separated by commas - essentially, in Python 2, you can stop the generator with `return`, but you can't return a value.</sub>

### Footnotes

1. <sub>The languages CLU, Sather, and Icon were referenced in the proposal
   to introduce the concept of generators to Python. The general idea is
   that a function can maintain an internal state and yield intermediate
   data points on demand by the user. This promised to be [superior in performance
   to other approaches, including Python threading](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/), which isn't even available on some systems.</sub>
2. <sub>This means, for example, that `range` objects aren't `Iterator`s, even though they are iterable, because they can be reused. Like lists, their `__iter__` methods return iterator objects.</sub>
3. <sub>`yield` was originally introduced as a statement, meaning that it
   could only appear at the beginning of a line in a code block.
   Now `yield` creates a yield expression.
   https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-yield_stmt
   This change was [proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#specification-sending-values-into-generators) to allow a user to send data into the generator just as
   one might receive it. To send data, one must be able to assign it to something, and
   for that, a statement just won't work.</sub>

Answer (score 460):

`yield` is just like `return` - it returns whatever you tell it to (as a generator). The difference is that the next time you call the generator, execution starts from the last call to the `yield` statement. Unlike return, **the stack frame is not cleaned up when a yield occurs, however control is transferred back to the caller, so its state will resume the next time the function is called.**

In the case of your code, the function `get_child_candidates` is acting like an iterator so that when you extend your list, it adds one element at a time to the new list.

`list.extend` calls an iterator until it's exhausted. In the case of the code sample you posted, it would be much clearer to just return a tuple and append that to the list.

Comment: This is close, but not correct.  Every time you call a function with a yield statement in it, it returns a brand new generator object.  It's only when you call that generator's .next() method that execution resumes after the last yield.

Answer (score 320):

There's one extra thing to mention: a function that yields doesn't actually have to terminate. I've written code like this:

```
def fib():
    last, cur = 0, 1
    while True: 
        yield cur
        last, cur = cur, last + cur
```

Then I can use it in other code like this:

```
for f in fib():
    if some_condition: break
    coolfuncs(f);
```

It really helps simplify some problems, and makes some things easier to work with.

Answer (score 311):

For those who prefer a minimal working example, meditate on this interactive Python session:

```
>>> def f():
...   yield 1
...   yield 2
...   yield 3
... 
>>> g = f()
>>> for i in g:
...   print(i)
... 
1
2
3
>>> for i in g:
...   print(i)
... 
>>> # Note that this time nothing was printed
```

Answer (score 293):

**TL;DR**

## Instead of this:

```
def square_list(n):
    the_list = []                         # Replace
    for x in range(n):
        y = x * x
        the_list.append(y)                # these
    return the_list                       # lines
```

## do this:

```
def square_yield(n):
    for x in range(n):
        y = x * x
        yield y                           # with this one.
```

Whenever you find yourself building a list from scratch, `yield` each piece instead.

This was my first "aha" moment with yield.

---

`yield` is a [sugary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) way to say

> build a series of stuff

Same behavior:

```
>>> for square in square_list(4):
...     print(square)
...
0
1
4
9
>>> for square in square_yield(4):
...     print(square)
...
0
1
4
9
```

Different behavior:

Yield is **single-pass**: you can only iterate through once. When a function has a yield in it we call it a [generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756342/673991). And an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884501/673991) is what it returns. Those terms are revealing. We lose the convenience of a container, but gain the power of a series that's computed as needed, and arbitrarily long.

Yield is **lazy**, it puts off computation. A function with a yield in it *doesn't actually execute at all when you call it.* It returns an [iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) that remembers where it left off. Each time you call `next()` on the iterator (this happens in a for-loop) execution inches forward to the next yield. `return` raises StopIteration and ends the series (this is the natural end of a for-loop).

Yield is **versatile**. Data doesn't have to be stored all together, it can be made available one at a time. It can be infinite.

```
>>> def squares_all_of_them():
...     x = 0
...     while True:
...         yield x * x
...         x += 1
...
>>> squares = squares_all_of_them()
>>> for _ in range(4):
...     print(next(squares))
...
0
1
4
9
```

---

If you need **multiple passes** and the series isn't too long, just call `list()` on it:

```
>>> list(square_yield(4))
[0, 1, 4, 9]
```

---

Brilliant choice of the word `yield` because [both meanings](https://www.google.com/search?q=yield+meaning) apply:

> **yield** — produce or provide (as in agriculture)

...provide the next data in the series.

> **yield** — give way or relinquish (as in political power)

...relinquish CPU execution until the iterator advances.

Comment: I like people like yourself. Explaining things clearly without unnecessary jargon

Comment: @D-odu if I've earned your compliment, the real people to thank are the many whose eyes have glazed over listening to me. I'll take credit for noticing and trying to avoid that.

Comment: @BobStein LOL "glazed eyes" I get that a lot as I found myself too steeped in `git` minutia and learned I really, really needed to crimp the firehose.

Comment: @qneill man I could use some minutia over at this [question I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77917288/673991) about VS Code not getting along with `git`. How did version control get so messy?

Comment: @bobstein - I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78189350/468252) over there but TBH I'm no VS Code guru.

Answer (score 248):

Yield gives you a generator.

```
def get_odd_numbers(i):
    return range(1, i, 2)
def yield_odd_numbers(i):
    for x in range(1, i, 2):
       yield x
foo = get_odd_numbers(10)
bar = yield_odd_numbers(10)
foo
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
bar
<generator object yield_odd_numbers at 0x1029c6f50>
bar.next()
1
bar.next()
3
bar.next()
5
```

As you can see, in the first case `foo` holds the entire list in memory at once. It's not a big deal for a list with 5 elements, but what if you want a list of 5 million? Not only is this a huge memory eater, it also costs a lot of time to build at the time that the function is called.

In the second case, `bar` just gives you a generator. A generator is an iterable--which means you can use it in a `for` loop, etc, but each value can only be accessed once. All the values are also not stored in memory at the same time; the generator object "remembers" where it was in the looping the last time you called it--this way, if you're using an iterable to (say) count to 50 billion, you don't have to count to 50 billion all at once and store the 50 billion numbers to count through.

Again, this is a pretty contrived example, you probably would use itertools if you really wanted to count to 50 billion. :)

This is the most simple use case of generators. As you said, it can be used to write efficient permutations, using yield to push things up through the call stack instead of using some sort of stack variable. Generators can also be used for specialized tree traversal, and all manner of other things.

Comment: Just a note - in Python 3, `range` also returns a generator instead of a list, so you'd also see a similar idea, except that `__repr__`/`__str__` are overridden to show a nicer result, in this case `range(1, 10, 2)`.

Answer (score 247):

It's returning a generator. I'm not particularly familiar with Python, but I believe it's the same kind of thing as [C#'s iterator blocks](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) if you're familiar with those.

The key idea is that the compiler/interpreter/whatever does some trickery so that as far as the caller is concerned, they can keep calling next() and it will keep returning values - *as if the generator method was paused*. Now obviously you can't really "pause" a method, so the compiler builds a state machine for you to remember where you currently are and what the local variables etc look like. This is much easier than writing an iterator yourself.

Comment: Actually, the method *is* paused; the *state machine* that keeps local variables and the “program counter” is the call frame object itself, because it lives in the heap and not in the stack.

Answer (score 221):

Here is an example in plain language. I will provide a correspondence between high-level human concepts to low-level Python concepts.

I want to operate on a sequence of numbers, but I don't want to bother myself with the creation of that sequence, I want only to focus on the operation I want to do. So, I do the following:

- I call you and tell you that I want a sequence of numbers that are calculated in a specific way, and I let you know what the algorithm is. 
  **This step corresponds to `def`ining the generator function, i.e. the function containing a `yield`.**
- Sometime later, I tell you, "OK, get ready to tell me the sequence of numbers". 
  **This step corresponds to calling the generator function which returns a generator object.** Note that you don't tell me any numbers yet; you just grab your paper and pencil.
- I ask you, "Tell me the next number", and you tell me the first number; after that, you wait for me to ask you for the next number. It's your job to remember where you were, what numbers you have already said, and what is the next number. I don't care about the details. 
  **This step corresponds to calling `next(generator)` on the generator object.**
  (In Python 2, `.next` was a method of the generator object; in Python 3, it is named `.__next__`, but the proper way to call it is using the builtin `next()` function just like `len()` and `.__len__`)
- … repeat the previous step, until…
- eventually, you might come to an end. You don't tell me a number; you just shout, "Hold your horses! I'm done! No more numbers!" 
  **This step corresponds to the generator object ending its job, and raising a `StopIteration` exception.**
  The generator function does not need to raise the exception. It's raised automatically when the function ends or issues a `return`.

This is what a generator does (a function that contains a `yield`); it starts executing on the first `next()`, pauses whenever it does a `yield`, and when asked for the `next()` value it continues from the point it was last. It fits perfectly by design with the iterator protocol of Python, which describes how to sequentially request values.

The most famous user of the iterator protocol is the `for` command in Python. So, whenever you do a:

```
for item in sequence:
```

it doesn't matter if `sequence` is a list, a string, a dictionary or a generator *object* like described above; the result is the same: you read items off a sequence one by one.

Note that `def`ining a function that contains a `yield` keyword is not the only way to create a generator; it's just the easiest way to create one.

For more accurate information, read about [iterator types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), the [yield statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield), and [generators](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 219):

There is one type of answer that I don't feel has been given yet, among the many great answers that describe how to use generators. Here is the programming language theory answer:

The `yield` statement in Python returns a generator. A generator in Python is a function that returns *continuations* (and specifically a type of coroutine, but continuations represent the more general mechanism to understand what is going on).

Continuations in programming languages theory are a much more fundamental kind of computation, but they are not often used, because they are extremely hard to reason about and also very difficult to implement. But the idea of what a continuation is, is straightforward: it is the state of a computation that has not yet finished. In this state, the current values of variables, the operations that have yet to be performed, and so on, are saved. Then at some point later in the program the continuation can be invoked, such that the program's variables are reset to that state and the operations that were saved are carried out.

Continuations, in this more general form, can be implemented in two ways. In the `call/cc` way, the program's stack is literally saved and then when the continuation is invoked, the stack is restored.

In continuation passing style (CPS), continuations are just normal functions (only in languages where functions are first class) which the programmer explicitly manages and passes around to subroutines. In this style, program state is represented by closures (and the variables that happen to be encoded in them) rather than variables that reside somewhere on the stack. Functions that manage control flow accept continuation as arguments (in some variations of CPS, functions may accept multiple continuations) and manipulate control flow by invoking them by simply calling them and returning afterwards. A very simple example of continuation passing style is as follows:

```
def save_file(filename):
  def write_file_continuation():
    write_stuff_to_file(filename)

  check_if_file_exists_and_user_wants_to_overwrite(write_file_continuation)
```

In this (very simplistic) example, the programmer saves the operation of actually writing the file into a continuation (which can potentially be a very complex operation with many details to write out), and then passes that continuation (i.e, as a first-class closure) to another operator which does some more processing, and then calls it if necessary. (I use this design pattern a lot in actual GUI programming, either because it saves me lines of code or, more importantly, to manage control flow after GUI events trigger.)

The rest of this post will, without loss of generality, conceptualize continuations as CPS, because it is a hell of a lot easier to understand and read.

Now let's talk about generators in Python. Generators are a specific subtype of continuation. Whereas **continuations are able in general to save the state of a *computation*** (i.e., the program's call stack), **generators are only able to save the state of iteration over an *iterator***. Although, this definition is slightly misleading for certain use cases of generators. For instance:

```
def f():
  while True:
    yield 4
```

This is clearly a reasonable iterable whose behavior is well defined -- each time the generator iterates over it, it returns 4 (and does so forever). But it isn't probably the prototypical type of iterable that comes to mind when thinking of iterators (i.e., `for x in collection: do_something(x)`). This example illustrates the power of generators: if anything is an iterator, a generator can save the state of its iteration.

To reiterate: Continuations can save the state of a program's stack and generators can save the state of iteration. This means that continuations are more a lot powerful than generators, but also that generators are a lot, lot easier. They are easier for the language designer to implement, and they are easier for the programmer to use (if you have some time to burn, try to read and understand [this page about continuations and call/cc](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/callcc.html)).

But you could easily implement (and conceptualize) generators as a simple, specific case of continuation passing style:

Whenever `yield` is called, it tells the function to return a continuation.  When the function is called again, it starts from wherever it left off. So, in pseudo-pseudocode (i.e., not pseudocode, but not code) the generator's `next` method is basically as follows:

```
class Generator():
  def __init__(self,iterable,generatorfun):
    self.next_continuation = lambda:generatorfun(iterable)

  def next(self):
    value, next_continuation = self.next_continuation()
    self.next_continuation = next_continuation
    return value
```

where the `yield` keyword is actually syntactic sugar for the real generator function, basically something like:

```
def generatorfun(iterable):
  if len(iterable) == 0:
    raise StopIteration
  else:
    return (iterable[0], lambda:generatorfun(iterable[1:]))
```

Remember that this is just pseudocode and the actual implementation of generators in Python is more complex. But as an exercise to understand what is going on, try to use continuation passing style to implement generator objects without use of the `yield` keyword.

Answer (score 171):

While a lot of answers show why you'd use a `yield` to create a generator, there are more uses for `yield`.  It's quite easy to make a coroutine, which enables the passing of information between two blocks of code.  I won't repeat any of the fine examples that have already been given about using `yield` to create a generator.

To help understand what a `yield` does in the following code, you can use your finger to trace the cycle through any code that has a `yield`.  Every time your finger hits the `yield`, you have to wait for a `next` or a `send` to be entered.  When a `next` is called, you trace through the code until you hit the `yield`… the code on the right of the `yield` is evaluated and returned to the caller… then you wait.  When `next` is called again, you perform another loop through the code.  However, you'll note that in a coroutine, `yield` can also be used with a `send`… which will send a value from the caller *into* the yielding function. If a `send` is given, then `yield` receives the value sent, and spits it out the left hand side… then the trace through the code progresses until you hit the `yield` again (returning the value at the end, as if `next` was called).

For example:

```
>>> def coroutine():
...     i = -1
...     while True:
...         i += 1
...         val = (yield i)
...         print("Received %s" % val)
...
>>> sequence = coroutine()
>>> sequence.next()
0
>>> sequence.next()
Received None
1
>>> sequence.send('hello')
Received hello
2
>>> sequence.close()
```

Comment: Cute! A [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) (in the Lisp sense). Not often one sees those!

Answer (score 167):

There is another `yield` use and meaning (since Python 3.3):

```
yield from <expr>
```

From *[PEP 380 -- Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)*:

> A syntax is proposed for a generator to delegate part of its operations to another generator. This allows a section of code containing 'yield' to be factored out and placed in another generator. Additionally, the subgenerator is allowed to return with a value, and the value is made available to the delegating generator.
>
> The new syntax also opens up some opportunities for optimisation when one generator re-yields values produced by another.

Moreover [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) will introduce (since Python 3.5):

```
async def new_coroutine(data):
   ...
   await blocking_action()
```

to avoid coroutines being confused with a regular generator (today `yield` is used in both).

Answer (score 155):

All great answers, however a bit difficult for newbies.

I assume you have learned the `return` statement.

As an analogy, `return` and `yield` are twins. `return` means 'return and stop' whereas 'yield` means 'return, but continue'

> 1. Try to get a num_list with `return`.

```
def num_list(n):
    for i in range(n):
        return i
```

Run it:

```
In [5]: num_list(3)
Out[5]: 0
```

See, you get only a single number rather than a list of them. `return` never allows you prevail happily, just implements once and quit.

> 2. There comes `yield`

Replace `return` with `yield`:

```
In [10]: def num_list(n):
    ...:     for i in range(n):
    ...:         yield i
    ...:

In [11]: num_list(3)
Out[11]: <generator object num_list at 0x10327c990>

In [12]: list(num_list(3))
Out[12]: [0, 1, 2]
```

Now, you win to get all the numbers.

Comparing to `return` which runs once and stops, `yield` runs times you planed.
You can interpret `return` as `return one of them`, and `yield` as `return all of them`. This is called `iterable`.

> 3. One more step we can rewrite `yield` statement with `return`

```
In [15]: def num_list(n):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     for i in range(n):
    ...:         result.append(i)
    ...:     return result

In [16]: num_list(3)
Out[16]: [0, 1, 2]
```

It's the core about `yield`.

The difference between a list `return` outputs and the object `yield` output is:

You will always get [0, 1, 2] from a list object but only could retrieve them from 'the object `yield` output' once. So, it has a new name `generator` object as displayed in `Out[11]: <generator object num_list at 0x10327c990>`.

In conclusion, as a metaphor to grok it:

- `return` and `yield` are twins
- `list` and `generator` are twins

Comment: This is understandable, but one major difference is that you can have multiple yields in a function/method. The analogy totally breaks down at that point. Yield remembers its place in a function, so the next time you call next(), your function continues on to the next `yield`. This is important, I think, and should be expressed.

Answer (score 142):

From a programming viewpoint, the iterators are implemented as [thunks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_(functional_programming)).

To implement concepts such as iterators, generators, concurrent execution via messages, etc., one uses [messages sent to a closure object](https://wiki.c2.com/?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent), which has a dispatcher, and the [dispatcher answers to "messages"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) (this concept comes from Simula and is the central part of [Smalltalk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2mh92d-T3Y)).

["*next*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is a message sent to a closure, created by the "*iter*" call.

There are lots of ways to implement this computation. I used mutation, but it is possible to do this kind of computation without mutation, by returning the current value and the next yielder (making it [referential transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)).  Racket uses a sequence of transformations of the initial program in some intermediary languages, one of such rewriting making the yield operator to be transformed in some language with simpler operators.

Here is a demonstration of how yield could be rewritten, which uses the structure of R6RS, but the semantics is identical to Python's. It's the same model of computation, and only a change in syntax is required to rewrite it using yield of Python.

> ```
> Welcome to Racket v6.5.0.3.
>
> -> (define gen
>      (lambda (l)
>        (define yield
>          (lambda ()
>            (if (null? l)
>                'END
>                (let ((v (car l)))
>                  (set! l (cdr l))
>                  v))))
>        (lambda(m)
>          (case m
>            ('yield (yield))
>            ('init  (lambda (data)
>                      (set! l data)
>                      'OK))))))
> -> (define stream (gen '(1 2 3)))
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 1
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 2
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 3
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 'END
> -> ((stream 'init) '(a b))
> 'OK
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 'a
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 'b
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 'END
> -> (stream 'yield)
> 'END
> ->
> ```

Answer (score 134):

Here are some Python examples of how to actually implement generators as if Python did not provide syntactic sugar for them:

**As a Python generator:**

```
from itertools import islice

def fib_gen():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

assert [1, 1, 2, 3, 5] == list(islice(fib_gen(), 5))
```

**Using lexical closures instead of generators**

```
def ftake(fnext, last):
    return [fnext() for _ in xrange(last)]

def fib_gen2():
    #funky scope due to python2.x workaround
    #for python 3.x use nonlocal
    def _():
        _.a, _.b = _.b, _.a + _.b
        return _.a
    _.a, _.b = 0, 1
    return _

assert [1,1,2,3,5] == ftake(fib_gen2(), 5)
```

**Using object closures instead of generators** (because [ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent))

```
class fib_gen3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b = 1, 1

    def __call__(self):
        r = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return r

assert [1,1,2,3,5] == ftake(fib_gen3(), 5)
```

Answer (score 123):

I was going to post "read page 19 of Beazley's 'Python: Essential Reference' for a quick description of generators", but so many others have posted good descriptions already.

Also, note that `yield` can be used in coroutines as the dual of their use in generator functions.  Although it isn't the same use as your code snippet, `(yield)` can be used as an expression in a function.  When a caller sends a value to the method using the `send()` method, then the coroutine will execute until the next `(yield)` statement is encountered.

Generators and coroutines are a cool way to set up data-flow type applications.  I thought it would be worthwhile knowing about the other use of the `yield` statement in functions.

Answer (score 105):

Here is a simple example:

```
def isPrimeNumber(n):
    print "isPrimeNumber({}) call".format(n)
    if n==1:
        return False
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def primes (n=1):
    while(True):
        print "loop step ---------------- {}".format(n)
        if isPrimeNumber(n): yield n
        n += 1

for n in primes():
    if n> 10:break
    print "writing result {}".format(n)
```

Output:

```
loop step ---------------- 1
isPrimeNumber(1) call
loop step ---------------- 2
isPrimeNumber(2) call
loop step ---------------- 3
isPrimeNumber(3) call
writing result 3
loop step ---------------- 4
isPrimeNumber(4) call
loop step ---------------- 5
isPrimeNumber(5) call
writing result 5
loop step ---------------- 6
isPrimeNumber(6) call
loop step ---------------- 7
isPrimeNumber(7) call
writing result 7
loop step ---------------- 8
isPrimeNumber(8) call
loop step ---------------- 9
isPrimeNumber(9) call
loop step ---------------- 10
isPrimeNumber(10) call
loop step ---------------- 11
isPrimeNumber(11) call
```

I am not a Python developer, but it looks to me `yield` holds the position of program flow and the next loop start from "yield" position. It seems like it is waiting at that position, and just before that, returning a value outside, and next time continues to work.

It seems to be an interesting and nice ability :D

Comment: You are correct. But what is the effect on flow which is to see the behaviour of "yield" ? I can change the algorithm in the name of mathmatics. Will it help to get different assessment of "yield" ?

Answer (score 90):

Here is a mental image of what `yield` does.

I like to think of a thread as having a stack (even when it's not implemented that way).

When a normal function is called, it puts its local variables on the stack, does some computation, then clears the stack and returns. The values of its local variables are never seen again.

With a `yield` function, when its code begins to run (i.e. after the function is called, returning a generator object, whose `next()` method is then invoked), it similarly puts its local variables onto the stack and computes for a while. But then, when it hits the `yield` statement, before clearing its part of the stack and returning, it takes a snapshot of its local variables and stores them in the generator object. It also writes down the place where it's currently up to in its code (i.e. the particular `yield` statement).

So it's a kind of a frozen function that the generator is hanging onto.

When `next()` is called subsequently, it retrieves the function's belongings onto the stack and re-animates it. The function continues to compute from where it left off, oblivious to the fact that it had just spent an eternity in cold storage.

Compare the following examples:

```
def normalFunction():
    return
    if False:
        pass

def yielderFunction():
    return
    if False:
        yield 12
```

When we call the second function, it behaves very differently to the first. The `yield` statement might be unreachable, but if it's present anywhere, it changes the nature of what we're dealing with.

```
>>> yielderFunction()
<generator object yielderFunction at 0x07742D28>
```

Calling `yielderFunction()` doesn't run its code, but makes a generator out of the code. (Maybe it's a good idea to name such things with the `yielder` prefix for readability.)

```
>>> gen = yielderFunction()
>>> dir(gen)
['__class__',
 ...
 '__iter__',    #Returns gen itself, to make it work uniformly with containers
 ...            #when given to a for loop. (Containers return an iterator instead.)
 'close',
 'gi_code',
 'gi_frame',
 'gi_running',
 'next',        #The method that runs the function's body.
 'send',
 'throw']
```

The `gi_code` and `gi_frame` fields are where the frozen state is stored. Exploring them with `dir(..)`, we can confirm that our mental model above is credible.

Answer (score 85):

[image]

Imagine that you have created a remarkable machine that is capable of generating thousands and thousands of lightbulbs per day. The machine generates these lightbulbs in boxes with a unique serial number. You don't have enough space to store all of these lightbulbs at the same time, so you would like to adjust it to generate lightbulbs on-demand.

Python generators don't differ much from this concept. Imagine that you have a function called `barcode_generator` that generates unique serial numbers for the boxes. Obviously, you can have a huge number of such barcodes returned by the function, subject to the hardware (RAM) limitations. A wiser, and space efficient, option is to generate those serial numbers on-demand.

Machine's code:

```
def barcode_generator():
    serial_number = 10000  # Initial barcode
    while True:
        yield serial_number
        serial_number += 1


barcode = barcode_generator()
while True:
    number_of_lightbulbs_to_generate = int(input("How many lightbulbs to generate? "))
    barcodes = [next(barcode) for _ in range(number_of_lightbulbs_to_generate)]
    print(barcodes)

    # function_to_create_the_next_batch_of_lightbulbs(barcodes)

    produce_more = input("Produce more? [Y/n]: ")
    if produce_more == "n":
        break
```

Note the `next(barcode)` bit.

As you can see, we have a self-contained “function” to generate the next unique serial number each time. This function returns a *generator*! As you can see, we are not calling the function each time we need a new serial number, but instead we are using `next()` given the generator to obtain the next serial number.

## Lazy Iterators

To be more precise, this generator is a *lazy iterator*! An iterator is an object that helps us traverse a sequence of objects. It's called *lazy* because it does not load all the items of the sequence in memory until they are needed. The use of `next` in the previous example is the *explicit* way to obtain the next item from the iterator. The *implicit* way is using for loops:

```
for barcode in barcode_generator():
    print(barcode)
```

This will print barcodes infinitely, yet you will not run out of memory.

**In other words, a generator *looks like* a function but *behaves like* an iterator.**

## Real-world application?

Finally, real-world applications? They are usually useful when you work with big sequences. Imagine reading a *huge* file from disk with billions of records. Reading the entire file in memory, before you can work with its content, will probably be infeasible (i.e., you will run out of memory).

Answer (score 81):

An easy example to understand what it is: `yield`

```
def f123():
    for _ in range(4):
        yield 1
        yield 2


for i in f123():
    print (i)
```

The output is:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: are you sure about that output?  wouldnt that only be printed on a single line if you ran that print statement using `print(i, end=' ')`?  Otherwise, i believe the default behavior would put each number on a new line

Comment: @user9074332, You're right, but it is written on one line to facilitate understanding

Answer (score 77):

Like every answer suggests, `yield` is used for creating a sequence generator. It's used for generating some sequence dynamically. For example, while reading a file line by line on a network, you can use the `yield` function as follows:

```
def getNextLines():
   while con.isOpen():
       yield con.read()
```

You can use it in your code as follows:

```
for line in getNextLines():
    doSomeThing(line)
```

***Execution Control Transfer gotcha***

The execution control will be transferred from getNextLines() to the `for` loop when yield is executed. Thus, every time getNextLines() is invoked, execution begins from the point where it was paused last time.

Thus in short, a function with the following code

```
def simpleYield():
    yield "first time"
    yield "second time"
    yield "third time"
    yield "Now some useful value {}".format(12)

for i in simpleYield():
    print i
```

will print

```
"first time"
"second time"
"third time"
"Now some useful value 12"
```

Answer (score 75):

(My below answer only speaks from the perspective of using Python generator, not the [underlying implementation of generator mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389812/how-are-generators-and-coroutines-implemented-in-cpython), which involves some tricks of stack and heap manipulation.)

When `yield` is used instead of a `return` in a python function, that function is turned into something special called `generator function`. That function will return an object of `generator` type. **The `yield` keyword is a flag to notify the python compiler to treat such function specially.** Normal functions will terminate once some value is returned from it. But with the help of the compiler, the generator function **can be thought of** as resumable. That is, the execution context will be restored and the execution will continue from last run. Until you explicitly call return, which will raise a `StopIteration` exception (which is also part of the iterator protocol), or reach the end of the function. I found a lot of references about `generator` but this [one](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#generators) from the `functional programming perspective` is the most digestable.

(Now I want to talk about the rationale behind `generator`, and the `iterator` based on my own understanding. I hope this can help you grasp the ***essential motivation*** of iterator and generator. Such concept shows up in other languages as well such as C#.)

As I understand, when we want to process a bunch of data, we usually first store the data somewhere and then process it one by one. But this *naive* approach is problematic. If the data volume is huge, it's expensive to store them as a whole beforehand. **So instead of storing the `data` itself directly, why not store some kind of `metadata` indirectly, i.e. `the logic how the data is computed`**.

There are 2 approaches to wrap such metadata.

1. The OO approach, we wrap the metadata `as a class`. This is the so-called `iterator` who implements the iterator protocol (i.e. the `__next__()`, and `__iter__()` methods). This is also the commonly seen [iterator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern#Python).
2. The functional approach, we wrap the metadata `as a function`. This is
   the so-called `generator function`. But under the hood, the returned `generator object` still `IS-A` iterator because it also implements the iterator protocol.

Either way, an iterator is created, i.e. some object that can give you the data you want. The OO approach may be a bit complex. Anyway, which one to use is up to you.

Answer (score 74):

In summary, the `yield` statement transforms your function into a factory that produces a special object called a `generator` which wraps around the body of your original function. When the `generator` is iterated, it executes your function  until it reaches the next `yield` then suspends execution and evaluates to the value passed to `yield`. It repeats this process on each iteration until the path of execution exits the function. For instance,

```
def simple_generator():
    yield 'one'
    yield 'two'
    yield 'three'

for i in simple_generator():
    print i
```

simply outputs

```
one
two
three
```

The power comes from using the generator with a loop that calculates a sequence, the generator executes the loop stopping each time to 'yield' the next result of the calculation, in this way it calculates a list on the fly, the benefit being the memory saved for especially large calculations

Say you wanted to create a your own `range` function that produces an iterable range of numbers, you could do it like so,

```
def myRangeNaive(i):
    n = 0
    range = []
    while n < i:
        range.append(n)
        n = n + 1
    return range
```

and use it like this;

```
for i in myRangeNaive(10):
    print i
```

But this is inefficient because

- You create an array that you only use once (this wastes memory)
- This code actually loops over that array twice! :(

Luckily Guido and his team were generous enough to develop generators so we could just do this;

```
def myRangeSmart(i):
    n = 0
    while n < i:
       yield n
       n = n + 1
    return

for i in myRangeSmart(10):
    print i
```

Now upon each iteration a function on the generator called `next()` executes the function until it either reaches a 'yield' statement in which it stops and  'yields' the value or reaches the end of the function. In this case on the first call, `next()` executes up to the yield statement and yield 'n', on the next call it will execute the  increment statement, jump back to the 'while', evaluate it, and if true, it will stop and yield 'n' again, it will continue that way until the while condition returns false and the generator jumps to the end of the function.

Answer (score 69):

**Yield is an object**

A `return` in a function will return a single value.

If you want **a function to return a huge set of values**, use `yield`.

More importantly, `yield` is a **barrier**.

> like barrier in the CUDA language, it will not transfer control until it gets
>   completed.

That is, it will run the code in your function from the beginning until it hits `yield`. Then, it’ll return the first value of the loop.

Then, every other call will run the loop you have written in the function one more time, returning the next value until there isn't any value to return.

Answer (score 67):

Many people use `return` rather than `yield`, but in some cases `yield` can be more efficient and easier to work with.

Here is an example which `yield` is definitely best for:

> **return** (in function)

```
import random

def return_dates():
    dates = [] # With 'return' you need to create a list then return it
    for i in range(5):
        date = random.choice(["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"])
        dates.append(date)
    return dates
```

> **yield** (in function)

```
def yield_dates():
    for i in range(5):
        date = random.choice(["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th", "5th", "6th", "7th", "8th", "9th", "10th"])
        yield date # 'yield' makes a generator automatically which works
                   # in a similar way. This is much more efficient.
```

> **Calling functions**

```
dates_list = return_dates()
print(dates_list)
for i in dates_list:
    print(i)

dates_generator = yield_dates()
print(dates_generator)
for i in dates_generator:
    print(i)
```

Both functions do the same thing, but `yield` uses three lines instead of five and has one less variable to worry about.

> > **This is the result from the code:**

[image: Output]

As you can see both functions do the same thing. The only difference is `return_dates()` gives a list and `yield_dates()` gives a generator.

A real life example would be something like reading a file line by line or if you just want to make a generator.

Answer (score 57):

The `yield` keyword simply collects returning results. Think of `yield` like `return +=`

Answer (score 55):

`yield` is like a return element for a function. The difference is, that the `yield` element turns a function into a generator. A generator behaves just like a function until something is 'yielded'. The generator stops until it is next called, and continues from exactly the same point as it started. You can get a sequence of all the 'yielded' values in one, by calling `list(generator())`.

Answer (score 50):

Yet another TL;DR

**Iterator on list**: `next()` returns the next element of the list

**Iterator generator**: `next()` will compute the next element on the fly (execute code)

You can see the yield/generator as a way to manually run the **control flow** from outside (like continue loop one step), by calling `next`, however complex the flow.

**Note**: The generator is **NOT** a normal function. It remembers the previous state like local variables (stack). See other answers or articles for detailed explanation. The generator can only be **iterated on once**. You could do without `yield`, but it would not be as nice, so it can be considered 'very nice' language sugar.

Answer (score 46):

Here's a simple `yield` based approach, to compute the fibonacci series, explained:

```
def fib(limit=50):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(limit):
       yield b
       a, b = b, a+b
```

When you enter this into your REPL and then try and call it, you'll get a mystifying result:

```
>>> fib()
<generator object fib at 0x7fa38394e3b8>
```

This is because the presence of `yield` signaled to Python that you want to create a *generator*, that is, an object that generates values on demand.

So, how do you generate these values? This can either be done directly by using the built-in function `next`, or, indirectly by feeding it to a construct that consumes values.

Using the built-in `next()` function, you directly invoke `.next`/`__next__`, forcing the generator to produce a value:

```
>>> g = fib()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
3
>>> next(g)
5
```

Indirectly, if you provide `fib` to a `for` loop, a `list` initializer, a `tuple` initializer, or anything else that expects an object that generates/produces values, you'll "consume" the generator until no more values can be produced by it (and it returns):

```
results = []
for i in fib(30):       # consumes fib
    results.append(i) 
# can also be accomplished with
results = list(fib(30)) # consumes fib
```

Similarly, with a `tuple` initializer:

```
>>> tuple(fib(5))       # consumes fib
(1, 1, 2, 3, 5)
```

A generator differs from a function in the sense that it is lazy. It accomplishes this by maintaining it's local state and allowing you to resume whenever you need to.

When you first invoke `fib` by calling it:

```
f = fib()
```

Python compiles the function, encounters the `yield` keyword and simply returns a generator object back at you. Not very helpful it seems.

When you then request it generates the first value, directly or indirectly, it executes all statements that it finds, until it encounters a `yield`, it then yields back the value you supplied to `yield` and pauses. For an example that better demonstrates this, let's use some `print` calls (replace with `print "text"` if on Python 2):

```
def yielder(value):
    """ This is an infinite generator. Only use next on it """ 
    while 1:
        print("I'm going to generate the value for you")
        print("Then I'll pause for a while")
        yield value
        print("Let's go through it again.")
```

Now, enter in the REPL:

```
>>> gen = yielder("Hello, yield!")
```

you have a generator object now waiting for a command for it to generate a value. Use `next` and see what get's printed:

```
>>> next(gen) # runs until it finds a yield
I'm going to generate the value for you
Then I'll pause for a while
'Hello, yield!'
```

The unquoted results are what's printed. The quoted result is what is returned from `yield`. Call `next` again now:

```
>>> next(gen) # continues from yield and runs again
Let's go through it again.
I'm going to generate the value for you
Then I'll pause for a while
'Hello, yield!'
```

The generator remembers it was paused at `yield value` and resumes from there. The next message is printed and the search for the `yield` statement to pause at it performed again (due to the `while` loop).

Answer (score 39):

**yield** is similar to return. The difference is:

**yield** makes a function iterable (in the following example `primes(n = 1)` function becomes iterable).
What it essentially means is the next time the function is called, it will continue from where it left (which is after the line of `yield expression`).

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

def primes(n = 1):
   while(True):
       if isprime(n): yield n
       n += 1 

for n in primes():
    if n > 100: break
    print(n)
```

In the above example if `isprime(n)` is true it will return the prime number. In the next iteration it will continue from the next line

```
n += 1
```

Answer (score 31):

In Python `generators` (a special type of `iterators`) are used to generate series of values and `yield` keyword is just like the `return` keyword of generator functions.

**The other fascinating thing `yield` keyword  does is saving the `state` of a generator function**.

So, we can set a `number` to a different value each time the `generator` yields.

Here's an instance:

```
def getPrimes(number):
    while True:
        if isPrime(number):
            number = yield number     # a miracle occurs here
        number += 1

def printSuccessivePrimes(iterations, base=10):
    primeGenerator = getPrimes(base)
    primeGenerator.send(None)
    for power in range(iterations):
        print(primeGenerator.send(base ** power))
```

Answer (score 30):

`yield` yields something. It's like somebody asks you to make 5 cupcakes. If you are done with at least one cupcake, you can give it to them to eat while you make other cakes.

```
In [4]: def make_cake(numbers):
   ...:     for i in range(numbers):
   ...:         yield 'Cake {}'.format(i)
   ...:

In [5]: factory = make_cake(5)
```

Here `factory` is called a generator, which makes you cakes. If you call `make_function`, you get a generator instead of running that function. It is because when `yield` keyword is present in a function, it becomes a generator.

```
In [7]: next(factory)
Out[7]: 'Cake 0'

In [8]: next(factory)
Out[8]: 'Cake 1'

In [9]: next(factory)
Out[9]: 'Cake 2'

In [10]: next(factory)
Out[10]: 'Cake 3'

In [11]: next(factory)
Out[11]: 'Cake 4'
```

They consumed all the cakes, but they ask for one again.

```
In [12]: next(factory)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0f5c45da9774> in <module>
----> 1 next(factory)

StopIteration:
```

and they are being told to stop asking more. So once you consumed a generator you are done with it. You need to call `make_cake` again if you want more cakes. It is like placing another order for cupcakes.

```
In [13]: factory = make_cake(3)

In [14]: for cake in factory:
    ...:     print(cake)
    ...:
Cake 0
Cake 1
Cake 2
```

You can also use for loop with a generator like the one above.

One more example: Lets say you want a random password whenever you ask for it.

```
In [22]: import random

In [23]: import string

In [24]: def random_password_generator():
    ...:     while True:
    ...:         yield ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(8)])
    ...:

In [25]: rpg = random_password_generator()

In [26]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     print(next(rpg))
    ...:
FXpUBhhH
DdUDHoHn
dvtebEqG

In [27]: next(rpg)
Out[27]: 'mJbYRMNo'
```

Here `rpg` is a generator, which can generate an infinite number of random passwords. So we can also say that generators are useful when we don't know the length of the sequence, unlike list which has a finite number of elements.

Answer (score 22):

All of the answers here are great; but only one of them (the most voted one) relates to **how your code works**. Others are relating to *generators* in general, and how they work.

So I won't repeat what generators are or what yields do; I think these are covered by great existing answers. However, after spending few hours trying to understand a similar code to yours, I'll break it down how it works.

Your code traverse a binary tree structure. Let's take this tree for example:

```
    5
   / \
  3   6
 / \   \
1   4   8
```

And another simpler implementation of a binary-search tree traversal:

```
class Node(object):
..
def __iter__(self):
    if self.has_left_child():
        for child in self.left:
            yield child

    yield self.val

    if self.has_right_child():
        for child in self.right:
            yield child
```

The execution code is on the `Tree` object, which implements `__iter__` as this:

```
def __iter__(self):

    class EmptyIter():
        def next(self):
            raise StopIteration

    if self.root:
        return self.root.__iter__()
    return EmptyIter()
```

The `while candidates` statement can be replaced with `for element in tree`; Python translate this to

```
it = iter(TreeObj)  # returns iter(self.root) which calls self.root.__iter__()
for element in it: 
    .. process element ..
```

Because `Node.__iter__` function is a generator, the code **inside it** is executed per iteration. So the execution would look like this:

1. root element is first; check if it has left childs and `for` iterate them (let's call it it1 because its the first iterator object)
2. it has a child so the `for` is executed. The `for child in self.left` creates a **new iterator** from `self.left`, which is a Node object itself (it2)
3. Same logic as 2, and a new `iterator` is created (it3)
4. Now we reached the left end of the tree. `it3` has no left childs so it continues and `yield self.value`
5. On the next call to `next(it3)` it raises `StopIteration` and exists since it has no right childs (it reaches to the end of the function without yield anything)
6. `it1` and `it2` are still active - they are not exhausted and calling `next(it2)` would yield values, not raise `StopIteration`
7. Now we are back to `it2` context, and call `next(it2)` which continues where it stopped: right after the `yield child` statement. Since it has no more left childs it continues and yields it's `self.val`.

The catch here is that every iteration **creates sub-iterators** to traverse the tree, and holds the state of the current iterator. Once it reaches the end it traverse back the stack, and values are returned in the correct order (smallest yields value first).

Your code example did something similar in a different technique: it populated a **one-element list** for every child, then on the next iteration it pops it and run the function code on the current object (hence the `self`).

I hope this contributed a little to this legendary topic. I spent several good hours drawing this process to understand it.

Answer (score 17):

The `yield` keyword in Python used to exit from the code without disturbing the state of local variables and when again the function is called the execution starts from the last point where we left the code.

The below example demonstrates the working of `yield`:

```
def counter():
    x=2
    while x < 5:
        yield x
        x += 1
        
print("Initial value of x: ", counter()) 

for y in counter():
    print(y)
```

The above code generates the Below output:

```
Initial value of x:  <generator object counter at 0x7f0263020ac0>
2
3
4
```

Comment: what is the meaning of x=2
x=x+1 in your code ?

Comment: @pippo1980 it is just to show that `x` in the `counter()` is not affected by the changes to `x` in the outer scope.

Answer (score 16):

### Can also send data back to the generator!

Indeed, as many answers here explain, using `yield` creates a `generator`.

You can use the `yield` keyword to **send data back to a "live" generator**.

#### Example:

Let's say we have a method which translates from english to some other language. And in the beginning of it, it does something which is heavy and should be done once. We want this method run forever (don't really know why.. :)), and receive words words to be translated.

```
def translator():
    # load all the words in English language and the translation to 'other lang'
    my_words_dict = {'hello': 'hello in other language', 'dog': 'dog in other language'}

    while True:
        word = (yield)
        yield my_words_dict.get(word, 'Unknown word...')
```

Running:

```
my_words_translator = translator()

next(my_words_translator)
print(my_words_translator.send('dog'))

next(my_words_translator)
print(my_words_translator.send('cat'))
```

will print:

```
dog in other language
Unknown word...
```

#### To summarise:

use `send` method inside a generator to send data back to the generator. To allow that, a `(yield)` is used.

Answer (score 12):

yield in python is in a way similar to the return statement, except for some differences. If multiple values have to be returned from a function, return statement will return all the values as a list and it has to be stored in the memory in the caller block. But what if we don't want to use extra memory? Instead, we want to get the value from the function when we need it. This is where yield comes in. Consider the following function :-

```
def fun():
   yield 1
   yield 2
   yield 3
```

And the caller is :-

```
def caller():
   print ('First value printing')
   print (fun())
   print ('Second value printing')
   print (fun())
   print ('Third value printing')
   print (fun())
```

The above code segment (caller function) when called, outputs :-

```
First value printing
1
Second value printing
2
Third value printing
3
```

As can be seen from above, yield returns a value to its caller, but when the function is called again, it doesn't start from the first statement, but from the statement right after the yield. In the above example, "First value printing" was printed and the function was called. 1 was returned and printed. Then "Second value printing" was printed and again fun() was called. Instead of printing 1 (the first statement), it returned 2, i.e., the statement just after yield 1. The same process is repeated further.

Comment: If you try to run this code, the `print(fun())` does not print numbers. Instead, it prints the representation of the generator object returned by `fun()` (something along the lines of `<generator object fun at 0x6fffffe795c8>`)

Comment: @FunnyGeeks I ran the same code on Jupyter Notebook, and it works fine. Also, the point here was to explain the working of yield keyword. The snippet is just for demo purpose.

Comment: I tried it in python2 and python3 in my cygwin console. It didn't work. https://github.com/ImAmARobot/PythonTest

Answer (score 9):

## Simple answer

When function contains at least one `yield` statement, the function automaticly becomes generator function. When you call generator function, python executes code in the generator function until `yield` statement occur. `yield` statement freezes the function with all its internal states. When you call generator function again, python continues execution of code in the generator function from frozen position, until `yield` statement occur again and again. The generator function executes code until generator function runs out without `yield` statement.

## Benchmark

Create a list and return it:

```python
def my_range(n):
    my_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        my_list.append(i)
        i += 1
    return my_list

@profile
def function():
    my_sum = 0
    my_values = my_range(1000000)
    for my_value in my_values:
        my_sum += my_value

function()
```

Results with:

```
Total time: 1.07901 s
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     9                                           @profile
    10                                           def function():
    11         1          1.1      1.1      0.0      my_sum = 0
    12         1     494875.0 494875.0     45.9      my_values = my_range(1000000)
    13   1000001     262842.1      0.3     24.4      for my_value in my_values:
    14   1000000     321289.8      0.3     29.8          my_sum += my_value



Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
     9   40.168 MiB   40.168 MiB           1   @profile
    10                                         def function():
    11   40.168 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       my_sum = 0
    12   78.914 MiB   38.746 MiB           1       my_values = my_range(1000000)
    13   78.941 MiB    0.012 MiB     1000001       for my_value in my_values:
    14   78.941 MiB    0.016 MiB     1000000           my_sum += my_value
```

Generate values on the fly:

```python
def my_range(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1

@profile
def function():
    my_sum = 0
    
    for my_value in my_range(1000000):
        my_sum += my_value

function()
```

Results with:

```
Total time: 1.24841 s
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           @profile
     8                                           def function():
     9         1          1.1      1.1      0.0      my_sum = 0
    10
    11   1000001     895617.3      0.9     71.7      for my_value in my_range(1000000):
    12   1000000     352793.7      0.4     28.3          my_sum += my_value



Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
     7   40.168 MiB   40.168 MiB           1   @profile
     8                                         def function():
     9   40.168 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       my_sum = 0
    10
    11   40.203 MiB    0.016 MiB     1000001       for my_value in my_range(1000000):
    12   40.203 MiB    0.020 MiB     1000000           my_sum += my_value
```

## Summary

The generator function needs a little more time to execute, than function which returns a list but it use much less memory.

Answer (score 8):

A simple use case:

```
>>> def foo():
    yield 100
    yield 20
    yield 3

    
>>> for i in foo(): print(i)

100
20
3
>>>
```

How it works: when called, the function returns an object immediately. The object can be passed to the next() function. Whenever the next() function is called, your function runs up until the next yield and provides the return value for the next() function.

Under the hood, the for loop recognizes that the object is a generator object and uses next() to get the next value.

In some languages like ES6 and higher, it's implemented a little differently so next is a member function of the generator object, and you could pass values from the caller every time it gets the next value. So if result is the generator then you could do something like y = result.next(555), and the program yielding values could say something like z = yield 999. The value of y would be 999 that next gets from the yield, and the value of z would be 555 that yield gets from the next. Python get and send methods have a similar effect.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, it's used to create an iterator out of function.
Think 'yield' as an append() to your function and your function as an array.
And if certain criteria meet, you can add that value in your function to make it an iterator.

```
arr=[]
if 2>0:
   arr.append(2)

def func():
   if 2>0:
      yield 2
```

the output will be the same for both.

The main advantage of using yield is to creating iterators.
Iterators don’t compute the value of each item when instantiated. They only compute it when you ask for it. This is known as lazy evaluation.

Comment: +1. Thanks for easy explanation, but request more as how in your or post's code, easy evaluation is being done. See no way how your two codes work differently.

Answer (score 5):

Generators allow to get individual processed items immediately (without the need to wait for the whole collection to be processed). This is illustrated in the example below.

```py
import time

def get_gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
        time.sleep(1)

def get_list():
    ret = []
    for i in range(10):
        ret.append(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    return ret


start_time = time.time()
print('get_gen iteration (individual results come immediately)')
for i in get_gen():
    print(f'result arrived after: {time.time() - start_time:.0f} seconds')
print()

start_time = time.time()
print('get_list iteration (results come all at once)') 
for i in get_list():
    print(f'result arrived after: {time.time() - start_time:.0f} seconds')
```

```
get_gen iteration (individual results come immediately)
result arrived after: 0 seconds
result arrived after: 1 seconds
result arrived after: 2 seconds
result arrived after: 3 seconds
result arrived after: 4 seconds
result arrived after: 5 seconds
result arrived after: 6 seconds
result arrived after: 7 seconds
result arrived after: 8 seconds
result arrived after: 9 seconds

get_list iteration (results come all at once)
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
result arrived after: 10 seconds
```

Answer (score 5):

### What does the `Yield` Keyword do ?

> `yield` keyword is used to create a generator function. A type of function that is memory efficient and can be used like an iterator object.

In simple terms, **the yield keyword will turn any expression that is given with it into a generator object and return it to the caller. Therefore, you must iterate over the generator object if you wish to obtain the values stored there.**

Definition alone cannot exaplain `yield` so here is a very simple **exampleA.py**:

```py
# example A
def getNumber():
    for r in range(1,10):
        return r
```

The above function will return only **1** even when it's called multiple times over a loop. Now if we replace keyword `return` with `yield` as in **exampleB.py**:

```py
# example B
def getNumber():
    for r in range(1,10):
        yield r
```

It will return **1** when first called **2** when called again then **3**,**4** and it goes to increment till **10**.

Although the **example B** is conceptually true but to call it in **python 3** we have to do the following:

```py
# example B
def getNumber():
    for r in range(1,10):
        yield r

g = getNumber() #instance
print(next(g)) #will print 1
print(next(g)) #will print 2
print(next(g)) #will print 3 and so on
```

Answer (score 5):

`yield` allows you to write smarter `for`-loops by factoring out the looping part to a separate method for easy reuse.

Suppose you need to loop over all non-blank rows of a spreadsheet and do something with each row.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows(): #from the panda package for reading excel 
  if row = blank: # pseudo code, check if row is non-blank...
    continue
  if past_last_row: # pseudo code, check for end of input data
    break
  #### above is boring stuff, below is what we actually want to do with the data ###
  f(row)
```

If you need to call `g(row)` in a similar loop, you might find yourself repeating the `for` statement plus the checks for valid rows, which is boring, complex and error-prone. We don't want to repeat ourselves (DRY principle).

You want to separate the code for checking each record from the code that actually process the rows, like `f(row)` and `g(row)` .

You could make a function that takes f() as input parameter, but it is much simpler to use `yield` in a method that does all the boring stuff about checking for valid rows in preparation for calling f():

```
def valid_rows():
  for i, row in df.iterrows(): # iterate over each row of spreadsheet
    if row == blank: # pseudo code, check if row is non-blank...
      continue
    if past_last_row: # pseudo code, check for end of input data
      break
    yield i, row
```

Note that each call of the method will return one next row, except that if all rows are read and the `for` finishes, the method will `return` normally. The next call will start a new `for` loop.

Now you can write iterations over the data without having to repeat that boring checking for valid rows (which is now factored out to its own method) like:

```
for i, row in valid_rows():
  f(row)

for i, row in valid_rows():
  g(row)

nr_valid_rows = len(list(valid_rows()))
```

That is all there is. Note that I have not used jargon like iterator, generator, protocol, co-routine. I think that this simple example applies to a lot of our day to day coding.

Answer (score 3):

Function - returns.

Generator - yields (contains one or more yields and zero or more returns).

```
names = ['Sam', 'Sarah', 'Thomas', 'James']


# Using function
def greet(name) :
    return f'Hi, my name is {name}.'
    
for each_name in names:
    print(greet(each_name))

# Output:   
>>>Hi, my name is Sam.
>>>Hi, my name is Sarah.
>>>Hi, my name is Thomas.
>>>Hi, my name is James.


# using generator
def greetings(names) :
    for each_name in names:
        yield f'Hi, my name is {each_name}.'
 
for greet_name in greetings(names):
    print (greet_name)

# Output:    
>>>Hi, my name is Sam.
>>>Hi, my name is Sarah.
>>>Hi, my name is Thomas.
>>>Hi, my name is James.
```

A generator looks like a function but behaves like an iterator.

A generator continues execution from where it is lefoff (or yielded). When resumed, the function continues the execution immediately after the last yield run. This allows its code to produce a series of values over time rather them computing them all at once and sending them back like a list.

```
def function():
    yield 1 # return this first
    yield 2 # start continue from here (yield don't execute above code once executed)
    yield 3 # give this at last (yield don't execute above code once executed)

for processed_data in function(): 
    print(processed_data)
    
#Output:

>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
```

Note:
Yield should not be in the try ... finally construct.

Answer (score 3):

### Key points

- The [grammar for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) uses the presence of the `yield` keyword to make a function that returns a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).
- A generator is a kind of [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), which is that main way that  looping occurs in Python.
- A generator is essentially a resumable function.  Unlike `return` that returns a value and ends a function, the `yield` keyword returns a value and suspends a function.
- When `next(g)` is called on a generator, the function resumes execution where it left off.
- Only when the function encounters an explicit or implied `return` does it actually end.

### Technique for writing and understanding generators

An easy way to understand and think about generators is to write a regular function with `print()` instead of `yield`:

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        print(x)
        print(x * 10)
```

Watch what it outputs:

```
>>> f(3)
0
0
1
10
2
2
```

When that function is understood, substitute the `yield` for `print` to get a generator that produces the same values:

```
def f(n):
    for x in range(n):
        yield x
        yield x * 10
```

Which gives:

```
>>> list(f(3))
[0, 0, 1, 10, 2, 20]
```

### Iterator protocol

The answer to "what yield does" can be short and simple, but it is part of a larger world, the so-called "iterator protocol".

On the sender side of iterator protocol, there are two relevant kinds of objects. The *iterables* are things you can loop over.  And the *iterators* are objects that track the loop state.

On the consumer side of the iterator protocol, we call [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on the iterable object to get a iterator.  Then we call [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on the iterator to retrieve values from the iterator.  When there is  no more data, a [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) exception is raised:

```
>>> s = [10, 20, 30]    # The list is the "iterable"
>>> it = iter(s)        # This is the "iterator"
>>> next(it)            # Gets values out of an iterator
10
>>> next(it)
20
>>> next(it)
30
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
StopIteration
```

To make this all easier for us, for-loops call iter and next on our behalf:

```
>>> for x in s:
...     print(x)
...   
10
20
30
```

A person could write a book about all this, but these are the key points.  When I teach Python courses, I've found that this is a minimal sufficient explanation to build understand and start using it right away.  In particular, the trick of writing a function with `print`, testing it, and then converting to `yield` seems to work well with all levels of Python programmers.

Answer (score 3):

**What Is Yield In Python?**

The Yield keyword in Python is similar to a return statement used for returning values or objects in Python. However, there is a slight difference. The yield statement returns a generator object to the one who calls the function which contains yield, instead of simply returning a value.

Inside a program, when you call a function that has a yield statement, as soon as a yield is encountered, the execution of the function stops and returns an object of the generator to the function caller. In simpler words, the yield keyword will convert an expression that is specified along with it to a generator object and return it to the caller. Hence, if you want to get the values stored inside the generator object, you need to iterate over it.

It will not destroy the local variables’ states. Whenever a function is called, the execution will start from the last yield expression. Please note that a function that contains a yield keyword is known as a generator function.

When you use a function with a return value, every time you call the function, it starts with a new set of variables. In contrast, if you use a generator function instead of a normal function, the execution will start right from where it left last.

If you want to return multiple values from a function, you can use generator functions with yield keywords. The yield expressions return multiple values. They return one value, then wait, save the local state, and resume again.

Source: https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/yield-in-python

Answer (score 3):

**`yield`**:

- can return a value multiple times from a function by stopping the function.
- can use `from` with it like `yield from`.
- is used when returning big data by dividing it into small pieces of data to prevent the big usage of RAM.

For example, `test()` below can return `'One'`, `'Two'` and `['Three', 'Four']` one by one by stopping `test()` so `test()` returns 3 times in total by stopping `test()` 3 times in total:

```py
def test():
    yield 'One'                  # Stop, return 'One' and resume 
    yield 'Two'                  # Stop, return 'Two' and resume
    yield from ['Three', 'Four'] # Stop and return ['Three', 'Four']
```

And, these 3 sets of code below can call `test()` and print `'One'`, `'Two'`, `'Three'` and `'Four'`:

```py
for x in test():
    print(x)
```

```py
x = test()
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
```

```py
x = test()
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
print(x.__next__())
```

This is the result:

```
$ python yield_test.py
One
Two
Three
Four
```

In addition, when using `return` with `yield`, there is no way to get the value from `return`:

```py
def test():
    yield 'One' 
    yield 'Two'
    yield from ['Three', 'Four']
    return 'Five' # 'Five' cannot be got

x = test()
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x))
print(next(x)) # Here
```

So, there is the error below when trying to get `'Five'`:

```
$ python yield_test.py 
One
Two
Three
Four
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\yield_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(next(x))
          ^^^^^^^
StopIteration: Five
```

Comment: `# 'Five' cannot be got` well, it can, if you catch the `StopIteration` error and look at the `.args[0]`

Answer (score 1):

To understand its yield function, one must understand what a generator is. Moreover, before understanding generators, you must understand *iterables*.
Iterable: iterable
To create a list, you naturally need to be able to read each element one by one. The process of reading its items one by one is called iteration:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
1
2
3
```

mylist is an iterable. When you use list comprehensions, you create a list and therefore iterable：

```
>>> mylist = [x*x for x in range(3)]
>>> for i in mylist:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

All data structures that can be used for... in... are iterable; lists, strings, files...

These iterable methods are convenient because you can read them at will, but you store all the values ​​in memory, which is not always desirable when you have many values.
Generator: generator
A generator is also a kind of iterator, a special kind of iteration, which can only be iterated once. The generator does not store all values ​​in memory, but generates values ​​on the fly:

generator: generator, generator, generator generates electricity but does not store energy;)

```
>>> mygenerator = (x*x for x in range(3))
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...    print(i)
0
1
4
```

As long as () is used instead of [], the list comprehension becomes the generator comprehension. However, since the generator can only be used once, you cannot execute for i in mygenerator a second time: the generator calculates 0, then discards it, then calculates 1, and the last time it calculates 4. The typical black blind man breaks corn.

The yield keyword is used in the same way as return, except that the function will return the generator.

```
>>> def createGenerator():
...    mylist = range(3)
...    for i in mylist:
...        yield i*i
...
>>> mygenerator = createGenerator() 
>>> print(mygenerator) 
<generator object createGenerator at 0xb7555c34>
>>> for i in mygenerator:
...     print(i)
0
1
4
```

This example itself is useless, but when you need a function to return a large number of values ​​and only need to read it once, using yield becomes convenient.

To master the yield, one need to be clear is that when a function is called, the code written in the function body will not run. The function only returns the generator object. Beginners are likely to be confused about this.

Second, understand that the code will continue from where it left off every time for uses the generator.

The most difficult part now is:

The first time for calls the generator object created from your function, it will run the code in the function from the beginning until it hits yield, and then it will return the first value of the loop. Then, each subsequent call will run the next iteration of the loop you wrote in the function and return the next value. This will continue until the generator is considered empty, which yields when there is no hit while the function is running. That may be because the loop has ended, or because you are no longer satisfied with "if/else".

Personal understanding I hope to help you!