# Error when using a Python constructor

Tags: python, constructor

```
class fileDetails :

    def __init__(self,host,usr,pwd,database):
        self.host=host
        self.usr.usr
        self.pwd=pwd
        self.database=database

    def __init__(self,connection,sql,path):
        self.connection=mysql_connection()
        self.sql=sql
        self.path=path
```

If I use the constructor then it gives an error:

```
onnetction = fileDetails('localhost',"root","",'bulsorbit')
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: Do you mean self.usr = usr, rather than self.usr.usr?

Comment: What resources are you using to learn Python?  Are you using a book?  A website?  Which book?  Which website?  Where did you see examples like this?

Comment: `__init__` is NOT a constructor method. Python has dedicated constructor method `__new__`, which is hardly used in everyday programming.

Answer (score 10):

The overloading of the constructor (or any other function) is not allowed in python. So you cannot define two `__init__` functions for your class.

You can have a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312695/python-problem-with-overloaded-constructors) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141545/overloading-init-in-python)

The main ideas are to use default values *or* to create 'alternate constructors' *or* to check the number and the type of your args in order to choose which method to apply.

```
def __init__(self, **args):
```

Then `args` will be a dictionary containing all the parameters. So you will be able to make the difference between

```
connection = fileDetails(host='localhost',usr="root",pwd="",database='bulsorbit')
```

and

```
connection = fileDetails(connection="...",sql="...",path="...")
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a single constructor with optional arguments.

```
def __init__(self,host='host',usr='user',pwd='pwd',database='db',connection=None,sql=None,path=None):
  if connection:
    # however you want to store your connection
    self.sql=sql
    self.path=path
  else:
    self.host=host
    self.usr.usr
    self.pwd=pwd
    self.database=database
```

Or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

In Python the functions in a class are stored internally in a dictionary (remember that constructors are just regular functions), and so only one function of the same name can exist. Therefore, when defining more than one functions with the same name the last one will overwrite all the previously defined ones and you'll end up with only one function.

I suggest you look into [keyword and default arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions) to see the proper way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use len() to choose the right branch:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 4: # network
            self.host = args[0]
            self.user = args[1]
            self.pwd = args[2]
            self.database = args[3]
        elif len(args) == 3: # database
            self.connection = mysql_connection() # maybe it's args[0]?
            self.sql = args[1]
            self.path = args[2]

def main():

    foo = Foo('localhost',"root","",'bulsorbit')
    print foo.host
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# output
# localhost
```

but, sine Explicit is better than implicit. maybe this is workable too:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        if initdata['style'] == 'network':
            self.host = initdata['host']
            self.usr = initdata['usr']
            self.pwd = initdata['pwd']
            self.database = initdata['database']
        elif initdata[style] == 'database':
            self.connection = mysql_connection()
            self.sql = initdata['sql']
            self.path = initdata['path']
def main():
    data = dict({'style': 'network',
                 'host': 'localhost',
                 'usr': 'root',
                 'pwd': '',
                 'database': 'database'})
    foo = Foo(data)
    print foo.host
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
# output
# localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to achieve this:

```
class FileDetails:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 3:
            self.conn, self.sql, self.path = args
        elif len(args) == 4:
            self.host, self.usr, self.pw, self.db = args
        else:
            # handle appropriately

fd1 = FileDetail('connstring', 'select * from foo', '/some/path')
print fd1.conn, fd1.sql, fd1.path

fd2 = FileDetail('host', 'user', 'pass', 'somedb')
print fd2.conn, fd2.usr, fd2.pw, fd2.db
```

Of course, you should do the appropriate type checking and error handling in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

On the side note: if you really, really, reallllllyyy must do JiP (Java in Python) then multiple dispatch methods **are** possible with some additional code eg. [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pydisp.html) and even beter: [here by *BDFL*](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=101605).

Personally I try to avoid using them.